# File not included in request body using AJAX inside a Laravel Project

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have two modals in my Laravel project, one for creation and one for edit. Each of the modals supports file upload. The idea is, that a user can upload a file during the creation and that file can be replaces during the edit process. Worth mentioning that the creation part works as expected.

**create-modal.blade.php**

```html
@hasVerified()
<div class="modal fade" id="create-case-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-auth" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content custom-modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn-without-style custom-modal-icon-close ms-auto" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('images/icons/cross-black.png') }}" alt="close">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center p-0 m-0 mt-1">
                <div class="custom-modal-body">
                    {{--First page modal--}}
                    <div class="js-modal-case-1-page">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">@lang('Create Case')</h2>
                        <p class="main-text margin-top-15">@lang('Fill in the fields to create a case')</p>
                        <div class="wrapper-basic-modal margin-top-30 margin-bottom-30">
                            <form action="{{ route('case.store') }}" method="POST" id="form-case"
                                  class="case-form js-form-case js-create-case-form" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                  accept-charset="utf-8">
                                @csrf
                                <input type="file" name="avatar" class="js-input-create-avatar-case"
                                       accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" hidden>
                                <div class="col-12 d-flex margin-top-30 z-index-1">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="{{ asset('images/global/default.png') }}"
                                             class="case-upload-avatar js-img-create-case-avatar" alt="Avatar">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="my-auto ms-4">
                                        <a href="javascript:void('Upload')"
                                           class="link-purple main-text-bold js-click-create-avatar-case">@lang('Cover Case')
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="name-case-modal"
                                           class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Name of the Business Case')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input id="name-case-modal" type="text" name="name" class="main-text"
                                           placeholder="@lang('Name of the Business Case')" autocomplete="name" value="">
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="desc-case-modal"
                                           class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Description')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea name="description" id="desc-case-modal"
                                              class="main-text" autocomplete="description"
                                              cols="15" rows="3" placeholder="@lang('Description')"></textarea>
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="problem-case-modal"
                                           class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Problem')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea name="problem" id="problem-case-modal"
                                              class="main-text" autocomplete="problem"
                                              cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="@lang('Problem')"></textarea>
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="requirement-case-modal"
                                           class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Requirements for the resolving')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea name="requirement" id="requirement-case-modal"
                                              class="main-text" autocomplete="requirement"
                                              cols="30" rows="3"
                                              placeholder="@lang('Requirements for the resolving')"></textarea>
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>

                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="delivery-date-modal"
                                           class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Delivery Date')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="date" name="delivery_date" class="main-text"
                                           id="delivery-date-modal" placeholder="@lang('Delivery Date')"
                                            min="{{ now() }}">
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="date-end-modal"
                                           class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Field')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <select class="form-select form-select-custom main-text-bold"
                                            name="field_knowledge_id" aria-label="Desc for select">
                                        <option value="0" selected>@lang('Open this select menu')</option>
                                        @foreach($fields as $field)
                                            <option value="{{$field->id}}">{{$field->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="modal-add-case-dropzone"
                                           class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Files')</label>
                                    <div class="dropzone js-data-dropzone" id="modal-add-case-dropzone">
                                        <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message><span>@lang('Drop files here to upload')</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="margin-top-30 justify-content-between">
                                    <button type="button" data-form=".case-form"
                                            class="btn btn-orange btn-submit-modal mx-auto js-form-btn-save">@lang('Choose package')
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{--Second page modal--}}
                    <div class="js-modal-case-2-page margin-bottom-30" style="display: none">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">@lang('Publish case')</h2>
                        <p class="main-text margin-top-15 margin-bottom-60">@lang('Choose Package')</p>
                        <div class="wrapper-basic-modal margin-top-30 margin-bottom-60">
                            @if($productActionPublication)
                            <form action="{{ route('shop.case.checkout') }}" method="POST"
                                  class="case-form js-form-case js-form-case-price" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                  accept-charset="utf-8">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-check text-start margin-top-25 mb-4">
                                    <input id="case" class="form-check-input disabled js-main-publish-case"
                                           type="checkbox" name="shop[0][price]"
                                           value="{{ $productActionPublication->product->st_price_id }}" checked>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="case">@lang('Publish case')</label>
                                    <span class="main-text-bold">
                                            {{ $productActionPublication->product->price }} €
                                        </span>
                                </div>
                                <p class="main-text-bold text-start mt-4 mb-3">@lang('Select how much of a solution you want to get for this')</p>
                                @foreach($packages as $key => $package)
                                    <div class="form-check text-start mb-3">
                                        <div class="mb-2">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" id="product{{ $key+1 }}" type="checkbox"
                                                   name="shop[{{ $key+1 }}][price]"
                                                   value="{{ $package->product->st_price_id }}">
                                            <label class="form-check-label main-text" for="product{{ $key+1 }}">
                                                {{ $package->product->name }} <span class="main-text-bold">{{ $package->product->price }} €</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <label class="form-check-label main-text" for="product{{ $key+1 }}">
                                            <span class="main-text">
                                            ({{ $package->product->description }})
                                        </span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach
                                @errortag()
                            </form>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="margin-top-30 d-flex justify-content-between mb-4">
                            <div class="w-100">
                                <button type="button" data-form=".case-form"
                                        class="btn btn-grey btn-submit-modal js-form-btn-back">@lang('Back')
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w-100 ms-4">
                                <button type="button" data-form=".case-form"
                                        class="btn btn-orange btn-submit-modal js-form-btn-publish-case">
                                <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm me-2 js-spinner" style="display: none;"
                                      role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    @lang('Publish case')
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endhasVerified()
```

**edit-modal.php**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-case-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-auth" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content custom-modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn-without-style custom-modal-icon-close ms-auto" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('images/icons/cross-black.png') }}" alt="close">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center p-0 m-0 mt-1">
                <div class="custom-modal-body">
                    <div class="">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">@lang('Edit') @lang('Case')</h2>
                        <p class="main-text margin-top-15">@lang('Fill in the fields to Update a case')</p>
                        <div class="wrapper-basic-modal margin-top-30 margin-bottom-60">
                            <form action="{{ route('case.update', $case) }}" method="POST" id="edit-case-form"
                                  class="edit-case-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
                                @csrf
                                @method('PUT')
                                <input type="text" name="is_draft" value="{{ $case->is_draft }}" hidden>
                                <input type="filee" name="avatar" class="js-input-create-avatar-case"
                                       accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" hidden>
                                <div class="col-12 d-flex margin-top-30 z-index-1">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="{{ $case->getFullUrlAvatar() }}"
                                             class="case-upload-avatar js-img-create-case-avatar" alt="Avatar">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="my-auto ms-4">
                                        <a href="javascript:void('Upload')" class="link-purple main-text-bold js-click-create-avatar-case">@lang('Cover Case')
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="name-case-modal" class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Name of the Business Case')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input id="name-case-modal" type="text" name="name" class="main-text js-case-name"
                                           placeholder="@lang('Name of the Business Case')" autocomplete="name" value="{{ $case->name }}">
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="desc-case-modal"
                                           class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Description')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea name="description" id="desc-case-modal"
                                              class="main-text js-case-desc" autocomplete="description"
                                              cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="@lang('Description')">{{ $case->description }}</textarea>
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>

                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="problem-case-modal"
                                           class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Problem')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea name="problem" id="problem-case-modal"
                                              class="main-text" autocomplete="problem"
                                              cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="@lang('Problem')">{{ $case->problem }}</textarea>
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="requirement-case-modal"
                                           class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Requirements for the resolving')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea name="requirement" id="requirement-case-modal"
                                              class="main-text" autocomplete="requirement"
                                              cols="30" rows="3"
                                              placeholder="@lang('Requirements for the resolving')">{{ $case->problem }}</textarea>
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="delivery-date-modal" class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Delivery Date')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="date" value="{{ $case->input_delivery_date }}" name="delivery_date" class="main-text" id="delivery-date-modal">
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="date-end-modal" class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Field')</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <select class="form-select form-select-custom main-text-bold" name="field_knowledge_id" aria-label="Desc for select">
                                        <option value="0" selected>@lang('Open this select menu')</option>
                                        @foreach($fields as $field)
                                            <option {{ $field->id == $case->field_knowledge_id ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $field->id }}">{{ $field->name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    @errortag()
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-input-group margin-top-25">
                                    <label for="modal-change-case-dropzone"
                                           class="main-text-bold margin-bottom-12">@lang('Files')</label>
                                    <div class="dropzone js-data-dropzone" id="modal-change-case-dropzone">
                                        <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message><span>@lang('Drop files here to upload')</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="margin-top-30">
                                    <button type="submit" data-form=".edit-case-form" class="btn btn-orange btn-submit-modal mx-auto js-form-btn-edit-case">@lang('Save')</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript which includes handling the file upload:
**case.js**

```js
    let files = [];
    let editFiles = [];

    // Initialize the Dropzone for the Add modal
    initDropzone($("#modal-add-case-dropzone"), files);

    // Initialize the Dropzone for the Edit modal
    initDropzone($("#modal-change-case-dropzone"), editFiles);

    function initDropzone(el, filesArray) {
        el.dropzone({
            url: "#",
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: false,
            parallelUploads: 1,
            maxFiles: 2,
            maxFilesize: 1024,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            acceptedFiles: "application/pdf",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
            },

            init: function () {
                let dropzoneInstance = this;

                if (window.existingFiles && window.existingFiles.length > 0) {
                    var existingFiles = window.existingFiles;

                    // TODO: Get requests sent wrongly
                    existingFiles.forEach(function (file) {
                        var mockFile = {
                            name: file.name,
                            size: file.size,
                            dataURL: file.url,
                        };

                        dropzoneInstance.displayExistingFile(
                            mockFile,
                            file.url
                        );

                        mockFile.previewElement.setAttribute("data-mock", "");
                    });
                }

                this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                    var mockPreviews = document.querySelectorAll(
                        ".dz-preview[data-mock]"
                    );
                    mockPreviews.forEach(function (preview) {
                        preview.remove();
                    });

                    while (dropzoneInstance.files.length > 1) {
                        dropzoneInstance.removeFile(this.files[0]);
                    }

                    filesArray.push(file);

                    $(
                        "#modal-add-case-dropzone #modal-change-case-dropzone .dz-file-preview .dz-progress"
                    ).each(function () {
                        $(this).hide();
                    });
                });

                this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
                    let index = filesArray.findIndex(
                        (item) => item.name === file.name
                    );
                    if (index !== -1) {
                        filesArray.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
            },
        });
    }

    $(".js-form-btn-edit-case").on("click", function (e) {
        let dataForm = new FormData(editForm[0]);

        $(editFiles)
            .filter(function () {
                return this !== undefined;
            })
            .each(function (index) {
                dataForm.append(`file[]`, this);
            });

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: editForm.attr("action"),
            data: dataForm,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                /*Checkout*/
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                notification("error", JSON.parse(error.responseText).message);
            },
        });
    });

    $(".js-form-btn-publish-case").on("click", function (e) {
        // e.preventDefault();
        let checkedProducts = 0;
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
            checkedProducts++;
        });
        if (checkedProducts >= 2) {
            /*Store case*/
            let dataForm = new FormData(form[0]);
            $(files)
                .filter(function () {
                    return this !== undefined;
                })
                .each(function (index) {
                    dataForm.append(`file[${index}]`, this);
                });
            preloader.addClass("preloader-modal");
            $(".js-spinner").show().parent().attr("disabled", true);
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: form.attr("action"),
                data: dataForm,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    /*Checkout*/
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: formPrice.attr("action"),
                        data: formPrice.serialize(),
                        success: function (response) {
                            // window.location.replace(response["url"]);
                            notification(
                                "success",
                                "Case created successfully"
                            );
                        },
                    });
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    notification(
                        "error",
                        JSON.parse(error.responseText).message
                    );
                },
            });
        } else {
            preloader.removeClass("preloader-modal");
            notification("error", "Please select at least 1 package");
        }
    });
```

The Laravel controller which handles the creation and update:
**BusinessCaseController.php**

```
<?php

...
class BusinessCaseController extends Controller
{

public $service;

public function __construct(BusinessCaseService $service)
{
    $this->service = $service;
}

...

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param BusinessCaseRequest $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(BusinessCaseRequest $request): Response
{
    if ($case = $this->service->create($request->validated())) {
        Session::push('case', $case->id);
        return response(['message' =>  __('notification.successfully created', ['Name' => __('Case')]) ], 200);
    }
    return response(['message' =>  __('notification.failed created', ['Name' => __('Case')]) ], 422);
}

/**
 * Update the specified Case in storage.
 *
 * @param BusinessCaseRequest $request
 * @param BusinessCase $case
 * @return RedirectResponse
 * @throws \Spatie\MediaLibrary\Exceptions\MediaCannotBeUpdated
 */
public function update(BusinessCaseRequest $request, BusinessCase $case): RedirectResponse
{
    if ($this->service->update($request->validated(), $case)) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('notification', ['type' => 'success', 'message' => __('notification.successfully updated', ['Name' => __('Case')]) ]);
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('notification', ['type' => 'error', 'message' => __('notification.failed updated', ['Name' => __('Case')])]);
}
```

}

The problem is that the file doesn't reach the controller, so the problem should be on client side.
I've checked the validator and also tried to send the request itself to the service and log the result, but no luck, the file is not present in case of edit.
The creation process works as expected, so definitely I am missing something in case of the edit process.
I am not interested at the server side logic of file updating, I will handle that later, after I'll have the necessary files there.

Comment: If the problem is really on the client side (which you could check through your browser's developer console), please remove the irrelevant parts (the PHP code and the corresponding tags) from your question. Also, share what you've tried to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase I've included the code from the controller also, because that the problem is on client side it's just my opinion. What I've tried is debugging the code, place logs everywhere and see what's happening. What I've found out is that the file isn't included in the request payload and I don't know how. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Why not check whether the problem is on the client or on the server side?

Comment: As I said, my opinion is that the problem is on client side. I've tried to find out the exact cause of the problem but I had no luck. I don't know why the file isn't added to the request payload in case of edit, but the creation part works. I tried to debug this for many hours and I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same problem and I solved it by creating a new FormData instance like this:

`var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('your_form_id'));`

then passing it as a parameter to the AJAX call.

Also in the AJAX call I set the `contentType` and `processData` parameters to false.

I hope it can help you